# unexpected token: '<function_name>' error when using hibernate, JPQL and postgres function

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpql

I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.6` with `Hibernate 5.4.8`, `Java 8` and Spring framework. I need to call a postgres function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_that_return_array(givenIds character varying(255)) RETURNS int[] AS
'
BEGIN
    RETURN string_to_array($1,'','');
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

within JPQL query

```java
private static final String JPQL_QUERY =
    " SELECT NEW com.package.CustomProjection( " +
    "  e.id, " +
    "  e.value " +
    " ) " +
    " FROM SomeEntity e " +
    " WHERE e.id = ANY(function_that_return_array(:ids))";
```

and using entity manager:

```java
@Autowired
private final EntityManager entityManager;

// ...

this.entityManager.createQuery(JPQL_QUERY, CustomProjection.class)
                .setParameter("ids", "1,2,3")
                .getResultList();
```

and it results in following exception:

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: function_that_return_array
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1055) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:748) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.subQuery(HqlBaseParser.java:3910) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.quantifiedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3515) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3373) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
...
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting EOF, found ')'
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:215) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
```

The above example is very simplified but it correctly represents the production problem. When I call above function in native SQL it works perfectly:

```sql
select *
from some_entity e 
where e.id = ANY(function_that_return_array('1,2,3,4'))
```

Does anyone know how to call a postgres function within JPQL and Hibernate or can point me out what I am doing wrong? I was reading many articles [like this one](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-call-postgresql-function/), SO questions and I was trying **dozens** of combinations but with no success so far. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate dialect you cannot call directly not registered custom database functions.
The exception in clear, hibernate knows nothing about your function:

```
unexpected token: function_that_return_array
```

You have two options here:

1. Call your function by generic mechanism for custom functions:

use

```
function('function_that_return_array', '1,2,3,4')
```

instead of

```
function_that_return_array('1,2,3,4')
```

2. Second option is to register your function:
   https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerFunction-java.lang.String-org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction-

Example:

```
public class MyDialect extends PostgreSQLXXDialect {
    public MyDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("function_that_return_array", new StandardSQLFunction("function_that_return_array"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately when using generic mechanism it throws the same exception with message `unexpected token: function`. I have also tried second approach with dialect registration. The breakpoint has been triggered inside constructor so my postgres function has been registered indeed. In addition I have called static `getFunctions()` method and it returned correctly our postgres function. But it still throws the same exception. Maybe it is a matter of library version or some missing dependency?

Comment: Or maybe it's because of function invocation inside `ANY` operator? Or some special quotes  are required as well?

Comment: function_that_return_array returns array of integers, so you can just use IN (...) operator, this is an equivalent for "ANY"

Comment: when I use `IN` operator it throws following error: `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]`. I've tried to use `TABLE` return type instead of `ARRAY` but hibernate fails as well. I've tried dozens of combinations but for some reason hibernate can't manage to convert JPQL into native SQL. It still throws either `unexpected token` or `unexpected end of subtree` depends of approach I try.  For comparison, when I'm using native query via the same entity manager it works properly.

Comment: `ANY` is a special quantifier in HQL, so you can't use it like this. You would have to pack the `ANY` into the function that you register.