# Using JPA query: search in postgres array and using 'in' clause in 1 query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

There's a filter endpoint to query on multiple properties. (Spring Boot 2.4.5 is used)
This is the entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "dbArray", typeClass = CustomArrayType.class)})
public class Organization implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @Column
  private String otherName;

  @Column(name = "organization_types")
  @Type(type = "dbArray")
  private List<String> organizationTypes;
}
```

`CustomArrayType` is a custom Hibernate `UserType`. In postgres, the definition of this column is `varchar[]`.

This is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {

@Query(
      value =
          "select o from Organization o where"
              + " (:organizationType is null OR :organizationType in (o.organizationTypes)) AND"
              + " (:otherNames is null OR o.otherName in (:otherNames))")
  List<Organization> findOrganizationByTypeAndOtherNamesIn(
      @Param("organizationType") String organizationType,
      @Param("otherNames") List<String> otherNames);
}
```

However, I get an exception with the following cause:
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 465`

I tried to use a native query:

```
@Query(
        value =
            "select * from organization o where"
                + " (:organizationType is null OR :organizationType = ANY(o.organization_types)) AND"
                + " (:otherNames is not null AND o.otherName in (:otherNames))",
        nativeQuery = true)
    List<Organization> findOrganizationByTypeAndOtherNamesIn(
        @Param("organizationType") String organizationType,
        @Param("otherNames") List<String> otherNames);
```

But unfortunately, I get the following cause:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 116
```

(position 116 is where `otherNames` query start).
I don't want to cast the `otherNames` to a `varchar`, because I provide a `List`, thus that will also not result in a working query.

Does anyone know how to get this query working in either a native query (postgres 10) or in JPQL?

Comment: Can you please check again removing `:otherNames is not null` part in your query ? I think this is where it is breaking

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom function e.g. `my_any` that wraps `o.organizationTypes` and renders the `any` "function". This question is similar to the following: [unexpected token: '<function_name>' error when using hibernate, JPQL and postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110948/unexpected-token-function-name-error-when-using-hibernate-jpql-and-postgre/68111684#comment120533930_68111684)

Then you could use it like this:

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {

@Query(
      value =
          "select o from Organization o where"
              + " (:organizationType is null OR :organizationType = my_any(o.organizationTypes)) AND"
              + " (:otherNames is null OR o.otherName in (:otherNames))")
  List<Organization> findOrganizationByTypeAndOtherNamesIn(
      @Param("organizationType") String organizationType,
      @Param("otherNames") List<String> otherNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have a couple of extra problem you haven't even run into yet, even if you solve these elegantly. Here's my suggestion. You'll need two of the queries to be native.

```java
@Query(value = "select o from Organization o where o.otherName in :otherNames")
List<Organization> findOrganizationByOtherNamesIn(
      @Param("otherNames") List<String> otherNames);
}

@Query(value = "select * from organization o where"
        + " array_position(o.organization_types, :organizationType) is not null "
        + " AND o.otherName in (:otherNames)",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<Organization> findOrganizationByTypeAndOtherNamesIn(
      @Param("organizationType") String organizationType,
      @Param("otherNames") List<String> otherNames);
}

@Query(value = "select * from organization o where"
        + " array_position(o.organization_types, :organizationType) is not null ",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<Organization> findOrganizationByType(
      @Param("organizationType") String organizationType);
}
```

And in your controller/service you call it like this:

```java
if (organizationType != null && otherNames != null && !otherNames.isEmpty()) {
// that isEmpty is vital to avoid a syntax error on an empty list
    repo.findOrganizationByTypeAndOtherNamesIn(organizationType, otherNames);
}
else if (otherNames != null && !otherNames.isEmpty()) {
    repo.findOrganizationByOtherNamesIn(otherNames);
}
else if (organizationType != null) {
    repo.findOrganizationByType(organizationType);
}
else {
    // this method already exists and is the default logic when both parameters are null
    repo.findAll();
}
```

Technically there is another possible workaround, but it still leaves you with a problem if that `otherNames` list is not null, but empty.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the if-else construction in the controller/service and only use 1 query. I know it is possible when I use raw postgres, so I hoped it would be possible with JPA as well. But unfortunately not. Thanks for your answer anyways!